# SupportMapFragment onDestroy handling when renavigating

Tags: kotlin, google-maps, android-fragments

Currently creating a subscreen of my app with a SupportMapFragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <LinearLayout
   
        <fragment
          android:id="@+id/map"
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
          tools:context=".MainActivity" />

       <Button
          android:id="@+id/back"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"

          android:text="@string/back"
       />

    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

From my Mainscreen I'm calling a change view function with a button in my MainActivity:

```
fun loadMapView(view: View) {
    mapFragmentManager= supportFragmentManager;
    
    // First navigation
    if (mapFragment==null){
        val mapFragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance()
        mapFragmentManager
        .beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.map, mapFragment!!)
        .commit()

        mapFragment!!.getMapAsync(this);
    }
    // Second, Third, ... Navigation
    else {
            mapFragmentManager
                .beginTransaction()
                .attach(mapFragment!!)
                .commit()
        }

        setContentView(R.layout.mapView) // Throwing Error when navigating second time
        
        // Setup Backbutton
        val back = findViewById<Button>(R.id.back)
        back.setOnClickListener {
            // Remove Mapfragment (also tried detach)
            mapFragmentManager.beginTransaction().remove(mapFragment!!).commit()

        // Navigate to main screen
        setActivityMain()
    }
```

First time navigating works totally fine, but navigating for a second time setContentView throws:

```
 Duplicate id 0x7f080180, tag null, or parent id 0xffffffff with another fragment for com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it on my own by changing the XML-tag to:

```
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/map"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.95"
     />
```

Than it works fine without checking for null:

```
 mapFragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance()
 mapFragmentManager
        .beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.map, mapFragment!!)
        .commit()

 mapFragment!!.getMapAsync(this);
```

and the button listener still includes:

```
mapFragmentManager.beginTransaction().remove(mapFragment!!).commit()
```